# How to prevent Create React App from forcing me to install TypeScript because a dependency has a ts file in it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, package.json

I have a React app created using `Create React App` that was running fine until today. Something must have updated the last time I installed a new package. Anyhow, so whenever I try to start the app, it complains that there are `.ts` files (within `node_modules` folder) and forces me to install TypeScript.

Is there any way to stop this behaviour? Because currently, installing TypeScript just opens a bottle of worms, where I need to resolve the TypeScript errors that arises.

Also, as the screenshot suggests, removing the tsconfig.json file doesn't resolve the issue, it gets automatically created on every run..
[image: Screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 0):

Currently because it's preventing me to work, I've done the following modification until they fix it on the Create React App:

**Current solution until they fix the create react app**

On the file `node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js`, find the definition of `verifyNoTypeScript()` (line 24). Replace the function to the following:

`function verifyNoTypeScript() {
  return true;
}`